# Get database table row with lowest column value above a minimum threshold

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter ecommerce website. I have a following table

```
shipping table

product_weight (in kgs)  shipping_charge
1.000                    60
1.500                    90
2.000                    120
2.500                    150
3.000                    180
3.500                    210
4.000                    240
```

I want to find the shipping charge for the products added into the cart. But i failed to calculate it. If product weight is 2.800 then i should get shipping_charge value 180. I dont know how to do it. below is my code

```
function get_shipping_charge(){
    $this->db->select('shipping_charge');
    $this->db->from('shipping_table');
    $this->db->where('product_weight >=', $product_weight);
    $this->db->limit('1');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Why you have limit in your query ? What is $product_weight that you passing in where ? and what you mean exactly by " If product weight is 2.800 then i should get shipping_charge value 180." and if so then what is >= in your query.
This is really confusing..can you please edit question ?

Comment: you are net calculation charge there you are just fetching one record from database .. can you explain little more. do you want to pass product and want to calculate the shipping charge ? and if the product weight more then 2.800 then shipping charge will be 180 ?

Comment: Make you question more clear? Exactly what you want to get form this query? You said you want to find but again you said you failed to calculate!

Comment: yes there is no need for limit.. but my question is clear.. i am not getting particular value of shipping_charge by the above query..

Comment: What are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_shipping_charge(){
$this->db->select('shipping_charge');
$this->db->from('shipping_table');
$this->db->where('product_weight >=', $product_weight);
$this->db->order_by("product_weight","ASC");
$this->db->limit('1');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
function get_shipping_charge() {
    $this->db->select('IFNULL(MAX(shipping_charge), (SELECT MIN(shipping_charge) FROM shipping_table))');
    $this->db->from('shipping_table');
    $this->db->where('product_weight <=', $product_weight);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Note**

*Query updated to handle weight values less than 1.000.*

Comment: Thanks, but it always shows max value of that column i.e. 240

Comment: @SureshK Please debug that your `$product_weight` contains for sure the value you're expecting. This answer should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function get_shipping_charge() {
    $this->db->select('MIN(shipping_charge) AS shipping_charge');
    $this->db->from('shipping_table');
    $this->db->where('product_weight >=', $product_weight);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it always shows min value of that column i.e. 60

Comment: Is the product_weight column varchar? If yes then you will have to type cast it to signed or change the column type to decimal or float. You can compare the product_weight as string if its varchar. Let me know if this works

Comment: try this: 
$this->db->query(select min(shipping_charge) as shipping_charge from shipping_table where product_weight >= 2.800);